# Is ubuntu 20.04 + android studio can run with 4GB of ram?

Tags: 20.04, ram, android-studio

I have never used ubuntu before. For the first time I'm going install ubuntu 20.04 on my PC. I checked the system requirements for 20.04 version - it requires 4GB of memory & my PC has only 4GB of memory. I need to run the Android Studio on it but Android Studio usually consumes a lot of memory. So my question is, Is 4GB RAM enough to run both ubuntu 20.04 version & Android Studio?

Comment: To aid your research: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/linux-windows-ram/ Opion based questions are not encouraged on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @karel question you suggested as similar was asked in 2018 & at that time ubuntu required only 2GB of ram but 20.04 version requires 4GB of ram. But it was helpful & I understand I need to upgrade my ram to at least 8GB.

Comment: @Changer If the duplicate link in the comment answered your question you can mark your question as a duplicate by clicking the link outside the text box of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will and better than windows.

Actually android studio was the reason which shifted me to ubuntu.